# Variable popen calls in C

Tags: c, windows, dos, popen

I'm trying to execute MS-DOS `DEL` commands inside a Win32 C program, and I already know that `system` and `popen` can be used for this. However, the problem is that both require string literals (type `const char`) for the commands, and I need something like the DOS equivalent of this Perl code (more or less, don't know if it actually works):

```
my $user = $ENV{'USERNAME'};
my $directory = $ENV{'HOME'};
my $files = system("dir " . $directory);
my $pattern = "s/(\d{7,8})|(\"" . $user . "\")/";
$files ~= $pattern;
system("rm " . $files);
```

which obviously *has to* use string literals for the `rm` command. Is there some other subprocess function in C that allows for char arrays as arguments for process names?

Comment: Why is it obvious that you can't use that sequence as a string literals ?

Comment: Because the system() and popen() functions specify that argument as type "const char".

Comment: A string literal is for most practical purposes a const char * , if you have a string, which in C is just a pointer to a sequnece of char's , terminated by a nul byte, you can pass it to popen/system,.

Comment: Oh, my bad. There was a typo in the question, but it's edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a pain, but you will probably end up having to un-escape all the escape characters. `"\blah"` -> `"\\blah"`, etc.  See a list of them [here](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1eschars.htm).

Based on your code, I would do something like (roughly):

```
pattern = "s/(\\d{7,8})|(\\\"%s\\\")/";
char buff[100];
sprintf(buff, getenv("HOME"));
system(buff);
```

The idea being specify the pattern with all the troubling characters escaped, i.e `\\` and `\"`, then use sprintf
to get the final format string.  The string from getenv will not have escape character problems, so you can use it directly.

Comment: Hmmm...ok, but that still doesn't explain how to filter an array of strings like "char filelist[256][256];" so that it can be concatenated into one space-separated string preceded by "DEL" to be fed into system(), which I just found out actually does take pointers to char arrays in addition to strings specified in the function call.

Comment: Well, I ended up coding my own solution with element-by-element array comparisons.  Thanks anyway.